# Как написать анализатор строки на prolog?

Tags: prolog

Есть строка-правило, например: "Если шея = длинная, и кожа = пятна, то животное = жираф.".
Как реализовать из такой строчки правила вида: animal(жираф, [длинная,пятна]).
И чтобы я к нему обратился так: animal(X,[длинная,пятна]) и он вернул X=жираф.

Мне кажется, что нужно с помощью `op` на прологе. Но не совсем понимаю как.

```
:- op(20,fx,esli).
:- op(25,fx,i).
:- op(30,fx,to).
:- op(15,xfx,=).

esli X1=T1 i X2=T2 to G=A :- assertz(animal(A, [T1,T2])).
```

Это не работает. И вопрос еще такой, как это реализовать, если параметров "и", будет больше. 
Например:
"Если шея = длинная, и кожа = пятна, и ноги = длинные, то животное = жираф."

Answer (score 0):

Сначала с помощью операции `op` как вы и хотели определяем недостающие операторы:

```
:- op(800, fx, if).
:- op(700, xfx, then).
:- op(200, xfy, and).
```

Учитывая, что параметров может быть больше, что важно определить приоритет операндом, что есть записать для `and` `xfy`, а не `xfx`.

После этого можно уже записать выражение:

```
if neck(long) and skin(spotty) and legs(long) then animal(giraffe).
```

Для простоты я использую не `=` а предикатную форму записи.

Сам интерпретатор правил можно записать следующим образом:

```
forward :-
    new_fact(P, Properties),
    P =.. [AtomName, AnimalName],
    Animal =.. [AtomName, AnimalName, Properties],
    assert(Animal).

new_fact(Concl, Prop) :-
    if Cond then Concl,
    composed_fact(Cond, [], Prop).

composed_fact(Cond, Props, [Prop | Props]) :-
    Cond =.. [_, Prop].

composed_fact(Cond1 and Cond2, Props, ResProp) :-
    composed_fact(Cond1, Props, Res1),
    composed_fact(Cond2, Res1, ResProp).
```

Тогда после запроса `forward`, вы сможете сделать запрос

```
?- animal(X, [long, spotty, long]).
X = giraffe.
```